# compiler errors using Boost.Python with macports Python.framework

Tags: boost-python, xcode4.4

This might be a very dumb question...

I'm trying to use Boost.Python in an Xcode project (boost 1.50, xcode 4.4, OS X 10.8). I installed both boost and python through macports. I dragged the macports Python framework (/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework) into the project and tried the most minimal program possible:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Py_Initialize();
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and get:

```
/opt/local/include/boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp:50:11: fatal error: 'pyconfig.h' file not found
```

Do I need to explicitly add the framework header folder to the project's header search paths? That seems irregular... so hopefully I'm just misunderstanding something?